# Setting up Logstash & ElasticSearch for custom log structure

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to setup logstash forwarding to redis/logstash/elasticsearch using https://github.com/jlecren/logserver (note -- this is my first attempt using these, so I may have some things way wrong).

However, the logs I want to send into elastic-search not a standard log format (it a custom application).  They are already in JSON format, so I'm simply trying to forward these up to redis.

I'm forwarding the JSON up to redis using logstash and this config:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/tmp/*.json"
      tags => "restserver"
      codec => "json"
   }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  redis { host => "192.168.33.101" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how to format the JSON output so I can search with kibana after they are in ES.  However, I think I'm missing how to create the ES template, and how to properly format the fields.

As a first pass, I've started with this JSON format (note -- this is just a first pass, more fields need to be added):

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2014-02-06T15:23:10-0000",
  "tags": {
    "serial": "XX2013111111",
    "command": "Thumbnail"
  },
  "ip": "10.6.1.21",
  "source": "XX2013111111",
  "fields": {
    "type": "Thumbnail",
    "controller": "Image",
    "thumbnail": {
      "datetaken": [
        "2014-02-06T13:22:35"
      ],
      "name": [
        "DCIM\\IMG_008736.JPG"
      ]
    }
  },
  "message": "....."
}
```

However, I'm confused about tag, fields, and how to create a template in ES (I think I need to do this, right?).

Is there a guide somewhere about new log formats and how to integrate into logstash/kibana/ES?

Comment: Since elasticSearch can dynamically adapt it's document structures, what is wrong with simply forwarding the logs to ES? Have you tried doing it? What exactly are your errors?